# Routes Not Drawing Correctly

Tags: vb.net, winforms, gmap.net

I'm using gmap.net library to implement map in my winforms application Using Following code i can draw routes in my map

```
Dim lstR As New List(Of PointLatLng)
```

And

```
Dim routes As New GMapOverlay("routes")
SpcMap.Overlays.Add(routes)
Dim r As New GMapRoute(lstR, "My car route")
routes.Routes.Add(r)
```

But The Problem is That it's Not Drawing route correctly it Just draws connecting lines between points in list I tried many code but can't figure out what i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This One
here you want to get route between Two perticulae points

```
Dim start As New PointLatLng(lstR(0).Lat, lstR(0).Lng)
    Dim ends As New PointLatLng(lstR(4).Lat, lstR(4).Lng)
    Dim route As MapRoute = GMapProviders.GoogleMap.GetRoute(start, ends, False, False, 13)
    Dim rs As New GMapRoute(route.Points, "Route1")
    Dim iOvrL As New GMapOverlay
    iOvrL.Routes.Add(rs)
    SpcMap.Overlays.Add(iOvrL)
```